# How to keep &quot; unchanged when calling parse function?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to parse a html string by using the parse function in Jsoup.

I have tried to read a lot of related posts and also the APIs, but still did not find the answer.

```
String html = "<p>&quot;others</p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse( html, "", Parser.xmlParser() );
...
System.out.println(doc.toString());
```

I want to get a result `<p>&quot;others</p>`, but instead I got `<p>"</p>`, where it changes `&quot;` to `"`. Is there any way I could keep it as `&quot;`?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the ampersand in the `&quot;` with the HTML for ampersand (`&amp;`).
This works to return your desired `'&quot;'` string when I insert it in a HTML page. 
Run the snippet to see what I mean.
Good luck!

```html
<p>&amp;quot;others</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `prettyPrint()` to false.

[jsoup prettyPrint()](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.OutputSettings.html#prettyPrint--)